# Carga de componentes para navegar con angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-router, routing

donde y como deberia colocar el  para que, al hacer click en un boton, se cargue solo la vista del nuevo componente. Actualmente mi problema es que se van cargan de manera que al hacer click en los botones, las vistas aparecen una arriba de la otra, generando una pagina larga en la que si scrolleo hacia abajo, sigue estando el componente anterior, comparto mi archivo de routing y el html donde uso los botones:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { IniciarSesionComponentComponent } from './iniciar-sesion-component/iniciar-sesion-component.component';
import { InicioComponentComponent } from './inicio-component/inicio-component.component';
import { RegistroComponentComponent } from './registro-component/registro-component.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'iniciar-sesion', component: IniciarSesionComponentComponent },
  { path: 'inicio', component: InicioComponentComponent },
  { path: 'registro', component:RegistroComponentComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid vh-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center m-0 p-0">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1>ScoutLink</h1>
      <h5>Tu talento merece ser descubierto.</h5>
      <div class="mt-4">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-dark btn-lg px-5 py-3 me-sm-3 fs-6 fw-bolder" routerLink="/iniciar-sesion" routerLinkActive="active">Iniciar Sesion</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-dark btn-lg px-5 py-3 me-sm-3 fs-6 fw-bolder" routerLink="/registro" routerLinkActive="active">Registrarse</a>
      </div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

El funcionamiento deberia ser, que al apretar iniciar sesion o registrarse, pase completamente a la vista de esos componentes, no que cargue el componente pero al scrollear hacia abajo siga estando la vista de app.component.html